# Range formula in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need to give as an argument to the function `COUNTIFS` the function that looks like in Javasctipt

```
   function range (a) {
      if(a>=6 && a<=12) {
      return true;
    }
      return false;
   }
```

I've tried to use something like this in the formula, but it hasn't worked.

```
AND(MIN(6);MAX(12))
```

The full formula looks like this

```
=COUNTIFS('Data_list'!G:G; $A2; 'Data_list'!L:L; $B2;'Data_list'!H:H; AND(MIN(6);MAX(12)))
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: You can use operators in COUNTIFS. See the [docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en).

Answer (score 2):

for example:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(--REGEXMATCH(FILTER(Data_list!H:H&"", 
 Data_list!G:G=A2, Data_list!L:L=B2), 
 "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, ROW(A6:A12))&"$")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: The different function... which (as I suspected) is probably not the "shorter way" OP was looking for. But maybe it is :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use operators in `COUNTIFS`, as demonstrated in the [docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en):

```
=COUNTIFS('Data_list'!G:G; $A2; 'Data_list'!L:L; $B2;'Data_list'!H:H; ">=6";'Data_list'!H:H; "<=12")
```

Comment: Yeah, I know this way of solving the trouble, but I'd like to find a shorter way.
Thank you anyway

Comment: You may be looking for a different function then. COUNTIFS doesn't work like that.